# JQuery Datepicker header text missing

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am trying to include a JQuery datepicker within a dialog box, but the header text has disappeared and I have no idea why!  I have the include .js and .css files in my header so they're generic and I have never seen this happen on any other page (I have datepicker included elsewhere).

Can anyone point me to a solution?  Even google isn't sure of my problem.....
[image: Jquery Datepicker]

// EDIT

Here is the relevant code I have for the datepicker; I didn't post initially as it's about as basic as it gets!

HTML code:

```
<div id="col1">Completion Date</div>
<div id="col2"><input id="compdate"></div>
```

JQuery creation of datepicker:

```
$(function() {
    $('#compdate').datepicker();
});
```

Comment: have you checked the console for the CSS you output? maybe something is overwriting datepicker's css

Answer (score 0):

Post some code you are using and/or console errors.

As you can see [here](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#localization), Datepicker can be localized - maybe try using the 
`$.datepicker.regional[ "" ]` - it should turn English language on

Comment: I've posted my code -- console shows no errors, CSS appears to be untouched.  I attempted the localization and that had no effect.  It works perfectly otherwise, when I attempt to highlight the text at the top of the datepicker, I can only highlight a small area which leads me to think the text just isn't there, not a different colour etc

Answer (score 0):

Woah .... thick moment has surpassed even my thick moments.

Left some CSS code in which became useless except for what it did to datepicker (and also highlights how dangerous a global CSS style can be...)

```
span {
    display: none;
}
```

I shall sit in a corner and think about my error...

Thanks all for the assistance!